# Authentication of Oracle Database from R Script

Tags: r, oracle, authentication

I have a production ready R script which fetches some data from an Oracle database. 
For development I have hardcoded it, but how do I authenticate it in production?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] in your question!

Comment: check out Oracle wallet + `ROracle`